# Handling image components as properties in React with styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a React project and the goal is to have no .css files. I'm currently refactoring existing .css code to make use of styled-components in a Typescript React project.

Previously images were being called as background in a .css class

```
a.item.overview {
  background: url(../img/overview.svg) no-repeat 16px 50% / 20px 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

The approach I've taken for the images was converting the .svg files into react components.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Icon from './Icon'

const Svg = styled(Icon)` 
    margin-top: 20px;
    fill: red;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    fill-rule:evenodd;
    clip-rule:evenodd;
`

export const OverviewIcon = () => ( 
    <Svg viewBox="0 0 20 20">  
        <path     
            d="X4.2,2.5k11.2c0...."
        />  
    </Svg>
)
```

What i'm trying to achieve now is to create a component that will allow me to pass my image component into it as a property.

Ideally I would have one menuItem component that I can just pass an image component to and add some text. Something like the example below.
[image]

I'm relatively new to React so if my approach is incorrect or convoluted, I'm happy to make a change.

This is the approach I've attempted but it hasn't worked

```
type Props = {
    image: React.ReactNode
  }

export const LMenuItem = ({image}: Props) => (
    <div>{image}</div>
)
```

Comment: why not to call the svg icon from the location and pass it to src={} of an img tag? if you want an example with component I can provide.

Comment: The idea is to have all the images as components opposed to files. Once the project is done, its compiled down and served as an npm package. So to avoid having to use webpack or some other packaging tool we're converting all the SVG's into styled components.

Comment: Please be more specific, what is the actual question? How to pass image path to styled component? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please show the desired code you wish to work

Comment: I'm trying to pass my image component(the second piece of code I pasted) into another, separate component as a property. I dont know how to do that or if that is even a good approach

Comment: So how its related so styled-components? Are you asking how to pass properties? There are examples in the docs. Please show **usage** example.

Comment: Please make reproducible example, your question is unclear [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you can create a sandbox for it. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)

Comment: do you mean you need a component for example **Iconimg(icon,text)**  that will return an icon with text?

Answer (score 0):

This approach finally worked.

```
type Props = {
    children: React.ReactNode
  }

export const LMenuItem = ({children}: Props) => (
    <div>{children}</div>
)
```